# Trigger.io when run ios don't open simulator

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, trigger.io

I'm trying to test an app with Trigger.io , but when I press run in ios my simulator doesn't show up. I ve no error in console and when I try run on web it work without problems.

what could be causing that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved the problem : it was just my version of Simulator not correct in the Trigger.io config json 6.1